# Uncaught module cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not found PhoneGap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, barcode

I had created a Phonegap android project in which I am trying to read a QRCode.For that I had included the library project Of BarcodeScanner from here https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner .

But while I am trying to add this library to my PhoneGap Project , Initially it shows green symbol but after that it turns in red cross.

I think because of that I am getting this log in Logcat :

**05-1512:48:37.489:D/DroidGap(863):onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

05-15 12:48:37.749: D/CordovaNetworkManager(863): Connection Type: 3g

05-15 12:48:37.749: D/DroidGap(863): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)

05-15 12:48:37.758: D/CordovaNetworkManager(863): Connection Type: 3g

05-15 12:48:37.768: D/DroidGap(863): onMessage(spinner,stop)

05-15 12:48:38.138: D/dalvikvm(863): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 222K, 4% free 8166K/8455K, paused 40ms, total 43ms

05-15 12:48:39.579: D/DroidGap(863): onMessage(spinner,stop)

05-15 12:48:42.718: I/Choreographer(863): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

05-15 12:48:44.508: D/CordovaLog(863): Uncaught module cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not found

05-15 12:48:44.508: E/Web Console(863): Uncaught module cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not  found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.6.0.js:50**

So I got stuck here.Any suggestion ?

Comment: did you mention the plugin name and path correctly?

Comment: plugin name is mention as per the guide :

<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>    
<plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"/>